# Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The server returned an unexpected value. Expected "HTTP/1.1 101", had ""

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I am new to socketIO and elephantIO and am trying to emit to a node server from a php file emit_test.php as bellow

```html
ini_set("display_errors",5);
include ("vendor/autoload.php");

use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X;
  $version = new Version1X("http://localhost:3001");
  $client = new Client($version);

     $client->initialize();
     $client->emit("new_order", ["test"=>"test", "test1"=>"test1"]);
     $client->close();
```

server.js file

```js
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var logger = require('winston');

logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {colorize: true, timestamp: true})

logger.info('SocketIO > listening on port ');

var app = express();
var http_server = http.createServer(app).listen(3001);

function emitNewOrder(http_server){
  var io = socket.listen(http_server);

  //first listen to a connection and run the call back function
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on("new_order", function(data){
      console.log(data);
      //io.emit("new_order", data)
    })

  })
}

emitNewOrder(http_server);
```

and i want the data from the emit_test.php file loged in a reciever php file
with the code

```html
<script>

  var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");


  socket.on("new_order", function (data) {
    console.log(data);

  });
  </script>
```

but on running the servers i get an error :

Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The server returned an unexpected value. Expected "HTTP/1.1 101", had ""

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by changing the version of ElephantIO.

in the emit_test.php I change:

```
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X;
$version = new Version1X("http://localhost:3001");
```

to this version

```
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version2X;
$version = new Version2X("http://localhost:3001");
```